# Building Windows Phone 8 game with Unity

Tags: windows-phone-8, unity-game-engine

In unity I tried selecting the Windows 8 Phone option and clicking build and run, however, it never shows up on my windows 8 phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows SDK was not properly installed.